# Date is copied as "Range" in Google Sheets Macro/Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am struggling with a potential minor issue in google Sheets. I simply want to copy a date value to another cell, without changing the date format, etc.

However, if I save the date in a var, the Logger finds "Range". I also tried formatting, but I ended up with wrong dates, current dates, or just nothing at all.

Hint: Cell 63,4 contains a date value, formatted as a date in the spreadsheet.

```
function test() {
  var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = as.getActiveSheet();
  var start = ss.getRange(63,4);
  var row = start.getRow();
  var col = start.getColumn();
  Logger.log(start);
  
  start = new Date(0);
  ss.getRange('C2').setValue(start);
  
  ...
  
}
```

After running this code, the log shows "RANGE".

Do you have an idea how to solve this? I think I am not saving the cell correctly, but I did not find any further ideas.

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation / issue:**

- That is because you are not getting the value and [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
  returns an instance of the [range class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).
- Keep in mind that if the value is a date you might want to use
  [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue()).

**Solution:**

*Replace:*

```
var start = ss.getRange(63,4);
```

*with:*

```
var start = ss.getRange(63,4).getDisplayValue();
```

and remove that part:

```
start = new Date(0);
```

since this will overwrite the current value that is assigned to `start` which is the desired date you want to get.

---

**Code snippet:**

```
function test() {
  var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = as.getActiveSheet();
  var start = ss.getRange(63,4).getDisplayValue(); // cell D63
  ss.getRange('C2').setValue(start);  
}
```